# Swagger2.0 to RAML conversion

Tags: restlet, swagger, raml

I want to convert given Swagger 2.0 file to RAML.

I used swagger2raml provided in https://github.com/8x8Cloud/swagger2raml which is not converting it. I also checked RESTLET but i don't know which API's to use.

Can someone please help on this? I need a Java based solution.

Comment: Have you reported your issue here: https://github.com/8x8Cloud/swagger2raml/issues ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get the Restlet Framework version 2.3.3, and use the following code. You will need:

- the org.restlet core module
- the org.restlet.ext.apispark extension and its dependencies

  ```
  import org.raml.emitter.RamlEmitter;
  import org.raml.model.Raml;
  import org.restlet.ext.apispark.internal.conversion.TranslationException;
  import org.restlet.ext.apispark.internal.conversion.raml.RamlTranslator;
  import org.restlet.ext.apispark.internal.conversion.swagger.v2_0.SwaggerUtils;
  import org.restlet.ext.apispark.internal.model.Definition;
  public class TestConversion {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws TranslationException {
          Definition definition = SwaggerUtils.getDefinition(
              "/tmp/refImpl.swagger", null, null);
          Raml raml = RamlTranslator.getRaml(definition);
          RamlEmitter re = new RamlEmitter();
          System.out.println(re.dump(raml));
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Try http://studio.restlet.com, it can converts between swagger 2.0, swagger 1.2 and RAML.

Comment: I want to do it programmatically, as I have to expose it as service.

To expose as a service, I need jars to support it.